# C# Connection timeout to oracle database when application pool recycles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timeout, odp.net, connection-timeout

We have a web page which uses ODP.Net to connect to oracle database from ASP MVC page. During the heavy user load if application pool recycles for any reason, than we get few connection timeout errors from internal oracle class.

Inner Exception: StackTrace:    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)

How can we handle this scenario ? what could be the reason for this error ?

Comment: I don't think this is related to application pool recycles. The problem is you have reached the max pool size. It's likely that you forgot to close your connection somewhere in your code which results in not returning the connection to the pool to serve other requests or your pool size is so small

Comment: When you forgot to close your connection, the connection will be closed eventually but it occurs only when the GC collects those objects. Therefore, there are many connections not being returned to the pool for quite long time and it would result in reaching your max pool size.

Comment: I am making the connection inside USING block so the connection is closing. This problem only happens sometimes so if connection was not being closed, we should see it often right ?

Comment: even if the connection is not closed immediately, we would not see this error if the server is not under heavy load because the connection is closed eventually by GC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a new connection string that differs per user or with some other variable parameter you can exceed your max connections.  Pooling only works if you use the exact same string.  Under the covers your "close" is ignored and the connection manager keeps the connection open.  In SQL Server you can see a connection reset in the trace console every time an existing connection is reused.

Oracle probably has something similar.

Tracing your connections and possibly connection resets will most likely shed some light on what is creating so many connections.

Comment: Same connection string from web.config